# Finding taylor series in Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

In the following question I am trying to find the Taylor series for,

$$f(x)=x^3\sin(x^2)$$

centered at $x=0$.

My first thought was to find the Taylor series for $\sin x$ then derive it to get my series I wanted but I am not quite sure how to do that.

I worked out the Taylor series for $f(x)=\sin(x)$ centered at $x=0$ and got,

$f(x)=\sin x, f(0)=0$
$f'(x)=\cos x, f'(0)=1$
$f"(x)=-\sin x, f''(0)=0$
$f'''(x)=-\cos x, f'''(0)=-1$
$f''''(x)=\sin x, f''''(0)=0$

So the Taylor series for $\sin x$ centered at $x=0$ is,

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}...$

But how do I use this to find the Taylor series for $f(x)=x^3\sin(x^2)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$\sin x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}...\tag 1$$
This series converges for all $x$ (just use the Ratio Test to verify it). Thus, replacing $x$ by $x^2$ in $(1)$ we get
$$\sin (x^2)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x^{2{(2n+1)}}}{(2n+1)!}=x^2-\frac{x^6}{3!}+\frac{x^{10}}{5!}-\frac{x^{14}}{7!}...\tag 2$$ Then multiply $x^3$ to $(2)$ we get
$$x^3\sin (x^2)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nx^3\frac{x^{2{(2n+1)}}}{(2n+1)!}=x^5-\frac{x^9}{3!}+\frac{x^{13}}{5!}-\frac{x^{17}}{7!}...\tag 3$$ Hence,
$$x^3\sin (x^2)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x^{4n+5}}{(2n+1)!}=x^5-\frac{x^9}{3!}+\frac{x^{13}}{5!}-\frac{x^{17}}{7!}...\tag 4$$

Answer (score 1):

You can find the Taylor series for $\sin(x^2)$ by plugging $x^2$ into the Taylor series for $\sin$. So $\sin(x^2) = x^2-x^6/3!+x^{10}/5!\ldots.$ Then multiply each term by $x^3$ to get the series for $x^3\sin(x^2).$

Comment: so $x^3\sin(x^2) = x^5-x^9/3!+x^{13}/5!\ldots.$

Comment: @user905 yes that's right

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$\sin(x^2)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{x^{2(2k+1)}}{(2k+1)!}$$

Comment: so so $x^3\sin(x^2) = x^5-x^9/3!+x^{13}/5!\ldots.$, but how do i put that in the form that you have?

Comment: @Masacrosso would $$x^3\sin(x^2)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{4n+5}}{(2n+1)!}$$ be the answer?

Comment: @user905 Yes, that is correct.